# How to share Drush code with the community?

Tags: drush

I created a simple Drush command. How can I share it with the community?
Do I need to create a module and add it to drupal.org ?

Answer (score 5):

If it's a useful Drush command, and one that you could see being used on a daily basis, the I'd suggest heading to the [Drush issue queue](http://drupal.org/project/issues/drush) and posting a feature request.  Then answer the feature request with a patch that adds the command.  Whether to not it's suitable for Drush core will most likely then be discussed and further action will be taken by the maintainers.

Another option as you mentioned, is to create a module form your command and submit it via the standard module submission process.

The *last* thing I would suggest it hassling the module maintainers on social media channels or e-mail.

Greg Anderson does sometimes frequent this site though, so he might be able to provide a preferred approach :-)

Comment: http://drupal.org/project/drush_extras may be a better queue than the main one.

Comment: Also if it's a drush command related to a given module, then you would ask that module's maintainer to include it, rather than the main Drush or Drush Extras - eg. for a drush command to manipulate Features then suggest it on the issue queue of the Features module.

Comment: It's a small features wich clear sessions of all users or as specific user. I'll contact Greg Anderson. Thanks

Comment: @bobylapointe  I actually submitted a similar request/patch a while ago: http://drupal.org/node/1611952

Comment: All of the answers here are good.  I'm happy to take small additions in the Drush Extras project, although that has been slightly neglected of late. A co-maintainer for Drush Extras would be welcome.

Comment: Also, if I see your command in a queue somewhere - e.g. if you put a "please review my Drush command that I put in some other module" in the Drush queue - I'll tweet about it if it's useful.

Comment: @greg_1_anderson I'd be willing to help where I can - it's about time I gave back to the community somewhere other than here ;-)  I'll contact you via d.o :)

Comment: @MPD yes it's very similar except the drupal version. I'll post it on Drush Extra. Thx

Answer (score 0):

Get an account on github.com or another code repository, upload your code, then encourage others to help to work on it with you. Get the word out about your code. Involve other people in your work. Find out about the processes of making new Drupal projects and interacting with the community.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure this answers the question.  How wold simply getting an account on GitHub or another code repo help share with the community?  Perhaps you could expand on the answer somewhat? :)